# How to move map with respect to user movement towards right side when user tap and hold some marker

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a map and I am putting markers on that map randomly.
After that, I have a tap and hold action on the marker, and while tapping and holding, I can move the markers on the map.
Now, the problem is when I tap and hold and move the marker to the extreme right/left/up/down, then in the same state (I'm holding the marker and I can move it), google maps should move right/left/up/down, according to the marker movement.

Likewise, the map movement should be automatic while scrolling on the map if the user is holding the pin.
I hope you understood my problem.
Any solutions..??